# Posh-Git – What does it do?

Tags: windows, git

I’ve been battling with Git on Windows for over a week now, trying to make it usable. I heard about Posh-Git for PowerShell, but I can’t seem to find any information about what it actually does.

Does Posh-Git replace the standard `git` command-line tool and syntax with alternatives that are reliable, intuitive, unlikely to change in a future version and display nicely on the screen?

Or does Posh-Git just modify the prompt?

Comment: Link to posh-git homepage: [posh-git on GitHub](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

Comment: The links are useful, but I've read them and the source code which is when it dawned on me that maybe Posh-Git doesn't really do anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I can tell from reading [the posh-git README](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/readme.md) and [the blog post “Better Git with PowerShell”](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx), posh-git does only two things:

- modifies the prompt – saves you having to run `git status` by putting some of that info in the prompt
- provides tab-completion – lets you type commands that use `git` more easily by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Thus, it does not change the `git` command-line tool or its syntax.

Comment: Can you vote this clear answer up if you use Posh-Git as of Dec 2012 and can confirm this is the case.

Comment: Rory is correct - posh-git does not change git itself, but rather just aims to give a better experience in PowerShell.

Comment: yeah but if I just want to do a git pull from powershell I don't see the need for it

Answer (score 1):

Posh-Git is useful for shell intergration.

You can't incooperate shell scripts on a windows box without this tool.

---

In my experience there are some subtle differences in conventions like backslashes used in path names.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just take a look at the source codes to see? [dahlbyk / posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git).

There's also a nice introduction to it [Better Git with PowerShell](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx).